# Ship Google Cloud Text to Speech WAV Files in Product?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

We used to have someone go into a recording studio to record speech for our software. Recently, the Google Cloud has become good enough so that we are considering to use the API instead. We went through the terms, and it seems that distributing the WAV results is not covered by the terms. Does anybody know if this is okay?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what exactly means "distributing the WAV results" for you.

In GCP all the data you upload or generate is owned by you according to [security policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/data-processing-terms#7-data-security). It is not accessible for anyone else than you, unless you explicitly grant access. So, in this case once you obtain the audio result from Text-To-Speech you decide how to distribute it.

Comment: Well lets say we make a GPS device for a car that must be able to work offline. We generate the audio and then ship it with the firmware of the GPS.

Comment: In that case Speech could help you to reduce the spent time to obtain the speech. Unfortunately, it can't help you to ship the WAV files onto the GPS device, it merely delivers a sound file to the program that requested it. I think you need one program to request the Speech service and obtain the sound files and other program to distribute such files onto your devices. The problem is that your devices are offline, so I think the second program can't be automated like the fist one (has to be manually downloaded per device).